# jScrollPane - How to get separate arrows for the scrollbar

Tags: jquery, image, scroll, jscrollpane

I'm using jScrollPane for jQuery to make the scrollbar look like the Windows 8 scrollbar (I'm making kind of a Metro/Modern UI mockup just for fun). I have the look of the scrollbar pretty down-pat, but I have a problem. There is no way (at least in the current version) to get a left arrow image, and a right arrow image (as I'm using horizontal scrolling, like in the Metro UI). I have seen questions around here and they show a jQuery light theme which gives you separate arrows (the Lozenge theme), but it's a pain in the butt and not at all what I'm looking for. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't you be able to modify the CSS for the class .jspArrow to display your arrow images as background images?

Looking at one of the demos [here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/arrow_positions.html), I see this css:

```
.jspArrow
{
    background: #50506d;
    text-indent: -20000px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Change it to something like:

```
.jspArrow
{
    background: url('your_arrow_img')
    text-indent: -20000px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

There are separate classes for jspArrowRight and jspArrowLeft that should help you further.

If that doesn't work, I know for sure that you can create "padding" for the scroll bar, they call it a gutter in the documentation. I would create the gutter and then use CSS pseudo before and after elements on the scroll bar track to render arrows.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, sorry for the delay, I've been out, but I don't want to do that because then it shows the same image for both top and bottom (or left and right). I want different images. And, umm, as far as I can tell, there is no .jspArrowRight and .jspArrowLeft without the Lozenge theme, right?

Comment: There are definitely arrowRight and arrowLeft classes added to them.